# Why is the text in my button not perfectly centered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am new to programming, and I have this small problem. The text in my button is on the x-as perfectly centered, but not in the y-as.
Is there something to fix this?

Comment: Please share your relevant HTML and CSS code in the question.

Comment: try to remove height and replace it with line-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At #homeknop css remove `height:50px` property and  add `line-height:50px`.

To align the text center(vertically and horizontally) add:

```
text-align: center;  //to align horizontally center
vertical-align: middle;  //to align vertically center
```

In your code u have already include `text-align:center`

so just add `line-height:50px`  then the button text will be automatically aligned to center

```css
#homeKnop{
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  opacity: 74%;
  background: #424dc7;
  color: #efeaef;
 
  line-height: 50px;       
 
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #929292;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto;
  padding:4px 5px 4px 11px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 3s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 3s;
  -ms-animation: fadein 3s;
  -o-animation: fadein 3s;
  animation: fadein 3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="homeKnop" href="home.html">Play Now</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

For #homeKnop instead of having `height: 50px;` change it `line-height: 50px;`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the *height* and use *padding top* and *bottom* to define height of the button with text being centered.

Answer (score 1):

> The line-height property specifies the height of a line.

Rather than using height property, try with line-height property.

```
#homeKnop{
 /* height: 50px; */
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the CSS padding attribute for the ID **#homeKnop** as given below.

```
padding: 16px 10px 4px 11px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property

```
#homeKeep {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

eg.,

```css
#homeKeep {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#424dc7;
    color:#efeaef;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<p id='homeKeep'>Play Now</p>
```

To learn more about [centering vertically and horizontally in css](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `height` property on the link is the problem.
Switch it with added padding like: `padding: 8px 5px 8px 11px` or whatever your fancy

Answer (score 0):

just Try this code replace your #homeKnop css

```
#homeKnop {
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    opacity: 74%;
    background: #424dc7;
    color: #efeaef;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #929292;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 12px 5px 4px 11px;
    top: 60vh;
    left: 40vw;
    right: 50vw;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s;
    -ms-animation: fadein 3s;
    -o-animation: fadein 3s;
    animation: fadein 3s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add this property

```
line-height: 50px;
```

Now you have to remove this extra properties

```
top: 60vh;
left: 40vw;
right: 50vw;
height: 50px;
```

Then your button will be perfectly centered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can center it changing you padding attribute.
I made something like this and it was more in the center.
DutchFight.css→#homeKnop

```
padding: 10px 5px 0px 5px;
```